# my sql delete command makes my db.insert to cause a crash

Tags: android, sql

```
public void(Budget budget){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();    
    db.delete(Budget.table_name, Budget.collum_id,  " = ?",  new String[]{String.valueOf(budget.getId())}
}
```

Comment: the phone pop up a dialog saying the app has stopped working

Answer (score 1):

You provided wrong parameters to delete method, right syntax is as below

```
delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

if you are confused with this syntax simply use

```
db.execSQL(DELETE FROM table WHERE condition1 AND condition2.....);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code this way you are getting data for reading.

```
public void(Budget budget){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();    
    db.delete(Budget.table_name, Budget.collum_id,  " = ?",  new String[]{String.valueOf(budget.getId())
    db.close();}
}
```

Comment: adding db.close causes an error placing it outside the brackets same results

Comment: have you add change SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();   this with your code

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
db.delete(Budget.table_name, Budget.collum_id + " = ?",  new String[]{String.valueOf(budget.getId())});
```

You want to delete not read from the db
Also change to

```
Budget.collum_id + " = ?"
```

Comment: i tried switching between getWritableDatabase to getReadabledatabase nothing changes

Comment: Did you change to `Budget.collum_id + " = ?"`